# Add tag functionality adds tags to every item in list instead of just the one its meant to be added to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am rendering a list of students and in the list I am adding a tag to the student the functionality works however the tag is added to every student instead of just the one that I specifically want the tag added to. I am also trying to filter my students by tags which i believe may be working properly except I am unable to be sure because every student gets the tags so the filter doesnt do much to it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function StudentProfile() {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [filteredStudents, setFilteredStudents] = useState([])
  const [filteredTags, setFilteredTags] = useState([])
  const [open, setOpen] = useState([])
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
  const [searchTags, setSearchTags] = useState('')


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setStudents(result.students);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredStudents(
      students.filter(s => {
        return s.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          || s.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      })
    )
  }, [search, students]);

  useEffect(() =>  {
    setFilteredTags(
      tags.filter(tag => {
        console.dir(tag.includes(searchTags))
         
      })
    )
  }, [ searchTags,students])
  
  // const add = (id) => {
  //   if(tags.includes(id)) {
  //     setTags(tags.filter(sid => sid !== id))
  //   } else {
  //     let newTags = [...tags]
  //     newTags.push(id)
  //     setTags(newTags)
  //   }
  // }

  const addTags = event => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.target.value !== '') {
      setTags([...tags, event.target.value])
       event.target.value = ''
      
    }
  }
  // const inputKeyDown = event => {
  //   const val = event.target.value
  //   if (event.key === 'Enter' && val) {
  //     if (
  //       tags.find(tag => tag.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())
  //     ) {
  //       return 
  //     }
  //     setTags(...tags, val)
  //     event.target.value = ''
  //   }
  // }

  const toggleOpen= (id) => {
    if (open.includes(id)) {
     setOpen(open.filter(sid => sid !== id))
    } else {
     let newOpen = [...open]
     newOpen.push(id)
     setOpen(newOpen)
    }
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div >

        <ul >
          <form >
            <input
              className='input'
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by name"
              id="name-input"
              onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              className='input'
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by tags"
              id="tag-input"
              onChange={e => setSearchTags(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>
          {filteredStudents.map(student => (
            <li className="studentProfile" key={student.id}>
              <img className='image' src={student.pic} />
              <div className="text">
                <h1 className='name'>{student.firstName}  {student.lastName}</h1>
                <div className='info'>
                <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
                <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
                <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
                <p>Average: {(student.grades.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(b) + a, 0))
                  / (student.grades.map((grade) => grade).length)}%
                </p>
                 <div >
            <ul>
                {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                    <li className='li' key={index}>
                        <span className='tag'>{tag}</span>
                        
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <input
                className="tags-input"
                type="text"
                onKeyUp={(event) => addTags(event)}
                
                placeholder="Press enter to add tags"
            />
        </div>
                {open.includes(student.id) ? (
                  <ul>
                    {student.grades.map((grade, index) => <li className='li' key={grade.id}>Test {index + 1}: {grade}%</li>)}
                  </ul>) : null}

                  
                  </div>
              </div>
                  <div className='button-flex'>
                    <button className="expand-btn" onClick={() => toggleOpen(student.id)}>{open.includes(student.id) ? '-' : '+'}</button>
                  </div>


                 
            </li>
            
          ))
          }
        </ul >
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default StudentProfile;
```

Comment: You should edit your question down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding a tag to a student. You're updating a tags array that isnt linked to your students.

What you could do : turn `tags` into an array of objects `{ student : student.id, tag : tagValue}` , or into a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: It makes sense that I am only updating a tags array that isnt linked to my students being the root of the problem. Although I am still having trouble even with the suggestion you provided